# Jupyter notebook syntax error in compilling code

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

got an error while trying to run the following code **please help**

**I have tried to run the below code but i keep getting an error**

```
import numpy
import nnfs

from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data

nnfs.init
class layer_Dense:
    def init_(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.01 + np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros(1, n_neurons)
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases

class Activation_Relu:
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output= np.maximum(0, inputs)
    
class Activation_Softmax:
    def forward(self, inputs):
        exp_values= np.exp(inputs - np.max(inputs, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        probabilities = exp_values / np.sum(exp_values, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        self.output = probabilities
  

X, y = spiral_data(classes=100, samples=3)
dense= layer_dense(2,3)
Activation1= Activation_Relu()
dense2= layer_dense(3,3)
Activation2= ()

dense.forward(X)
Activation1.forward(dense.output)
dense2.forward(Activation1.output)
print(activation2.output[:5])
```

[image: The Error]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThkU.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/312gR.png
**Please Help**

Comment: you seem to be missing a closing parenthesis in the previous line

Comment: Please avoid to add images, add the error in plain text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing parenthesis in the last line of the code below:

```
class Activation_Softmax:
    def forward(self, inputs):
        exp_values= np.exp(inputs - np.max(inputs, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```